# Sending direct password to recovery email instead of password reset link

Tags: email, security, password-recovery

I sent direct passwords in password recovery emails.
Although I send the recovery email only if email is verified?

But I experienced that all the popular web systems sends reset links instead of passwords.

I want to know is there any disadvantage of sending direct password instead reset link?

Comment: Emails are completely insecure, and can be read by any number of people or machines.  However a reset link can be clicked on only a trackable number of times and once a reset link is used, and a new password is generated then the reset link can be disabled., it is ***FAR*** more secure than sending a plaintext password in an email

Comment: Hi. This would get a better response at [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: [Read this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124214/sending-password-reset-links-in-email) and [read this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148862/why-are-one-time-password-reset-links-safer-than-one-time-passwords)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question is more suitable for Security Stack Exchange where this exact question has multiple Q&A (so is in fact a duplication on another SE site)